# SELECT Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to make the same sql SELECT for every row.

But, I get a problem in the 'showReader = sqlShowSol.ExecuteReader();'

It says - **"Syntax error in query.  Incomplete query clause."**

Why is it?

```
-- connection was established before. --

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand sqlShowSol = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        sqlShowSol.Connection = connection;

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader showReader;

        int row = 1;

        while (true)
        {

            sqlShowSol.CommandText = "SELECT Q_A,Content FROM @userName WHERE id = @id;";
            sqlShowSol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
            sqlShowSol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row);
            showReader = sqlShowSol.ExecuteReader();

|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

There is more code afterwords...
But I get the problem in the last line I typed here.
```

Tnx 4 help,

Etay

Comment: (1) You cannot parameterize table names.  (2) Something seems wrong if "UserName" is the name of a table.

Comment: (3) OLE DB needs `?` parameter markers in the query text instead of parameter names.  Values are passed by ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
"SELECT Q_A,Content FROM @userName WHERE id = @id;";
```

You are using a paramater incorrectly. You are not permitted to use a parameter as the table name. The database engine cannot interpret the @userName reference.